# Crystal Report: Date Filter Working Incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I created a Crystal Report on C# Web Application and implemented the date filter function by adding parameter fields. My parameter fields are startdate and enddate.

I have used the record selection formula:

```
Date({SPR_Reload;1.DateRecorded}) >= {?startdate} and Date({SPR_Reload;1.DateRecorded}) <= {?enddate}
```

I have also used a stored procedure to retrieve the data I need. I have successfully run the report but I can only retrieve one data.

Situation:

Sample data: 
2/1/2014
2/4/2014
2/7/2014

If I've chosen Start Date - 2/1/2014; End Date - 2/7/2014, only one data will be shown.

2/7/2014 will be the one be shown on the report.

How can I show all the data between the chosen dates? Thanks

Comment: what is the data type of {SPR_Reload;1.DateRecorded} field if it is date then why should place it into Date() function.

Comment: The data type of the field was in date. It shows the date and time if the Date() was removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already working. It turned out that I forgot to remove the old suppression code.